# Passing hash reference to multiple functions in Perl

Tags: perl, hash, hash-reference

I have following code in Perl where a hash reference is passed from main function to func1 and then to func2. In func2 hash is updated. I want to access the updated hash in main function. Also there is a while loop in main function and i am expecting the hash should be updated during every iteration. The code might not look logical, but i have just written the skeleton of the code. I always get empty hash when i try to print the hash in main function

```
sub main {
      my %hash1;
      while (some condition)
      {
        my $i=0;
        if($i==0)
        { 
          func1($i,\%hash1);                      
          $i=1;
        }
        else
        {  
          func1($i,\%hash1);                      
          $i=0;
        }
      }
      foreach my $a (keys %hash1)
      {
        print "$hash1{$a}";
      }       
}
sub func1
{    
my ($i,$hash1)=@_;
----
if($i==0)
{ 
   func2($hash1);       
}

}

sub func2
{
my ($hash2)=@_;
$hash2->{key1}=1;
$hash2->{key2}=2;
}
```

Comment: Please check your code, since there is one closing } too much and it is unclear where your while-loop starts and where it ends.

Comment: Thanks Erik...I made the change

Comment: Correcting for the missing } and supplying a condition for the code you gave results in working code.  The hash values are set.  Please share the actual code with which you are having a problem.

Comment: BTW IMHO a sub is called with a leading & in Perl - so the code should be &func1(), ... But Adam is right. Your abstraction of your problem is not usefull to dertect your problem and help you.

Comment: I have updated the code...So you can see the func2 is called only when i=0. If during the last iteration i=1, the hash is empty

Comment: I mean: naked i is not variable $i at all.

Comment: what happens in `func2` if you copy dereference your hash like this: `%hash3 = %$hash2` and then use `%hash3`?

Comment: The code does not look like valid perl to me, and does not show the problem. Provide a working code we can copy and debug so that we can work on your problem by running the code on our machines

Comment: @Sam `int i` and `sub main` is not perl (well, you can `sub` whatever you want, but you do not need a main in a perl program). You should learn the basic syntax before learning about passing hash references.

Comment: @Dallaylaen `Can't locate warnigns.pm in @INC`  ;)

Comment: @Sam: Drop the else in your while - it never can be reached, since in the beginning of your while-loop you always declare $i=0 - so everytime the first if-statement will be true. It's pretty annoying to get a randomly changing, invalid and not able to run code of you here!

Comment: Oh... `use warnings;`, sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I see. You *think* it's not printing anything as a result of the hash's being empty. But it's *really* not printing anything because you're not giving it anything *to run*. You're giving it stuff to *compile*, but nothing to *run*.

`sub main` means nothing in Perl. In order to get that to run, you have to put somewhere on your mainline `main();` Then provided that you comment out the `---` on line 25, you'll get the output you expect.

This is why printing stuff out yourself is either 1) a bit more typing, or 2) not reliable. You saw nothing and thought our hash was empty. When really, the code never even got to the declaration. So, here's a hint, on the command line:

```
 cpan Smart::Comments
```

And then, in your code:

```
use Smart::Comments;
...

### %hash1
```

That way an empty hash looks like this:

```
### %hash1: {}
```

And the one that you expect, looks like this:

```
### %hash1: {
###           key1 => 1,
###           key2 => 2
###         }
```

Without *calling* the `main` sub, your output looks like this:

(yes, it is blank)

Otherwise, there is nothing wrong with your *passing* the hash.